# org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: java, selenium, web-testing

I am trying to test the GeeksForGeeks UI. When I click the tutorials dropdown, then select languages and select Java, it links to a new page and the following error occurs org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException. How can I solve this issue? I have tried all the possible solutions from stackoverflow.

```
public class SeleniumTest {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "driver/chromedriver.exe");
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGeeksForGeeksR() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/");
        WebElement tutorialsMenu = driver.findElement(By.className("header-main__list-item"));
        tutorialsMenu.click();
        List<WebElement> tutorialsList = tutorialsMenu.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        for (WebElement li : tutorialsList) {
            if (li.getText().equals("Languages")) {
                li.click();
                List<WebElement> languages = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
                for (WebElement a : languages) {
                    if (a.getText().equals("Java")) {
                        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
                        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(a));
                        a.click();
                        WebElement title = driver.findElement(By.className("entry-title"));
                        assertEquals("Java Programming Language", title.getText());

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    }

}
```

Solution:

```
@Test
    public void testGeeksForGeeksR() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/");
        WebElement tutorialsMenu = driver.findElement(By.className("header-main__list-item"));
        tutorialsMenu.click();
        List<WebElement> tutorialsList = tutorialsMenu.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        WebElement javaLanguage = null;
        for (WebElement li : tutorialsList) {
            if (li.getText().equals("Languages")) {
                li.click();
                List<WebElement> languages = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
                for (WebElement a : languages) {
                    if (a.getText().equals("Java")) {
                        javaLanguage = a;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        javaLanguage.click();
        driver.switchTo().activeElement();
        WebElement title = driver.findElement(By.className("entry-title"));
        assertEquals("Java Programming Language", title.getText());
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
```

Comment: What line gives you that exception?

Comment: Where I click the a tag -> a.click()

Comment: But it actually comes from this line -> if(a.getText().equals("Java")). I have just uploaded a screenshot of the failure trace

Comment: Does this occur after the clicking on `Java` link and the page `https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java/?ref=ghm` is presented or this page never opened?

Comment: Yes, this occurs after clicking on Java and the page https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java/?ref=ghm is presented.

Comment: OK, now it's clear without need to make actual debug :) I'll give an answer shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking on the `a` element with `Java` text the [`Java Programming Language`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java/?ref=ghm) page is opened.
At this point all the element references collected on the previous page are becoming `Stale`.
Generally, each Selenium `WebElement` object is actually a reference (pointer) to physical web element object.
So, when you are opening another web page or refreshing the existing page (reloading the web elements there) all the references to the web elements on the previous web page are no more valid.
In the Selenium terminology this situation is called [Stale Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/WebDriver/Errors/StaleElementReference).
Getting back to your specific code flow.
Looks like your target here is to open the [`Java Programming Language`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java/?ref=ghm) page. If so, all what you are missing here is to exit your loop once that page is opened and finish the test.
In case you wish to continue opening another tutorials from the menu on the main page you will have to go back from the internal page you opened and then get all the elements you wish to use there again.

Comment: I have added a break statement and now it works.

Comment: Apart from the question, I like this part. `Generally, each Selenium WebElement object is actually a reference (pointer) to physical web element object.` Thank you Prophet.

Comment: Thanks @deokyongsong! I think it's important to make people understand how things working.